# Ruby CSV to separate columns with unicode character

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file delimited by the thorn character. I can do:

```
CSV.foreach(file_path, { encoding:'ISO8859-1', :col_sep => "þ" }) do |row|
```

But I want to be safe with parsing my file and separate columns with a unicode version of thorn.

I think I'm on the right path with trying different options from within the call, like:

```
CSV.foreach(file_path, { encoding:'unicode', :col_sep => "U+00DE" }) do |row|
```

But I can't figure it out...

How should I be doing this in Ruby?

Thanks

Comment: you mean like this? `"\u00DE"`

Comment: Looks legit. But would still get "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8". Should encoding read something else?

Comment: `unicode` isn’t an encoding. It’s a standard that defines several encodings such as UTF-8 (probably the most common), UTF-16, UTF-32 and some others. How you represent `þ` in your source code only depends on your source encoding, not on the encoding of the CSV file. If you have an encoding “magic comment”, or are using utf-8 (the default source encoding) in Ruby 2.0 you will be okay with a literal `þ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
CSV.foreach(file_path, { encoding:'ISO-8859-1', :col_sep => "\u00FE" }) do |row|
```

Thank you @phoet

Worked this out, doing:

```
Encoding.name_list.each do |encoding|
  CSV.foreach(file_path, { encoding:encoding, :col_sep => "\u00FE" }) do |row|
    puts row.inspect
    break
  end
end
```

Fun

Comment: please accept this answer, eventhough it is your own. others won't have to try answering it then.